# Extra HTML Table cell appearing under table only on print/print preview

Tags: html, printing, html-table

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNSLJ.png) When I print my document every table prints an extra cell right under the table (but just one). I have looked everywhere on the net to find a solution. So far, I haven't been able to find it. I'm using Chrome. I haven't tried anything significant because I can't find the issue on the internet yet. Maybe it is just me. please help.

Here is my code:

```
<style>

body {padding: 0px; 
  margin: 0px; 
  text-align: center;}

.noborder th {font-weight: bold; 
          border: none; 
          padding: 0px, 3px;}

.noborder td {font-weight: regular; 
          border: none; 
          padding: 0px, 3px;}

table.border {empty-cells:show;}

.border th {font-weight: bold; 
        padding: 0px, 3px;}

.border td {font-weight: regular; 
        border: 1px solid gray; }
</style>

<table class="noborder" width="100%">
   <th width="50%">Phone: 855-359-9999
   <th width="50%">Fax: 888-965-1964
      <tr width="100%">
</table>

<p>

<table class="noborder" width="100%">
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="15%">___ Outpatient
         <td width="15%">___ Office
         <td width="15%">___ Inpatient
         <td width="15%">___ DME
         <td width="40%">___ Ambulatory Surgery Center
</table>

<p>

<table class="border" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%"><b>ICD-10 CM Diagnosis</b>
         <td width="50%"><b>Code</b>
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%"><b>Description</b>
         <td width="50%"><b>Code</b>
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
         <td width="50%">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="100%" colspan="2"><b>Special circumstances:</b>
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="100%" colspan="2">&nbsp;
         <tr width="100%">
         <td width="100%" colspan="2">&nbsp;
      <tr width="100%">
         <td width="100%" colspan="2"><b>Clinical Information:</b>
</table>
```

Comment: I made a codepen with your code and I do not see the extra cell at the bottom. It looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add closing tags to tr and td, like:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     some stuff between
  </td>
</tr>
```

I copy pasted your code into the text editor and it does not have closing tags but I don't have a problem as shown on your image. I opened the inspector in the browser and saw that browser put all the closing tags.

Just add closing tags to all trs and tds, and everything should work as intended.

Comment: I wish that would have worked but it did not, thanks for trying. it is very frustrating.